# why doesn't it insert image in database

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-image

I want to insert images in my database but image aren't inserted in database but text is inserted in the database. I'm fetching data from a server in JSON but text is added but image is not added in the database I want when JSON is loaded then imageurl is stored in the database and after its offline i access that

My code is:

**Database**

```
public class DataBasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "MyApp";
private static final String TABLE_TEXTS= "texts";
private static final String TABLE_IMAGES= "images";
private static final String TABLE_SPINNER = "spinners";
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "_name";
private static final String KEY_SPIN = "_spin";
private static final String KEY_URL = "url";

 private static final String CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_IMAGES
    + " ( "
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
    + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
    + KEY_URL + " TEXT) ";

 public DataBasehelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
    Log.e("table name","==>"+CREATE_TABLE_TEXTS);
    Log.e("table name","==>"+CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_IMAGES);
     onCreate(db);
 }

 public void addImage(ImgModel model) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, model.getName());
        values.put(KEY_URL, model.getImageUrl());
        db.insert(TABLE_TEXTS, null, values);
        Log.e("this db","value is"+values);
        db.close();
     }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("problem",e+"");
     }
 }
 public List<ImgModel> getAllImage() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<ImgModel> imageList = null;
    try{
        imageList = new ArrayList<ImgModel>();
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TEXTS;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
        if(!cursor.isLast())
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                ImgModel image = new ImgModel();
                image.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                image.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                image.setImageUrl(cursor.getString(2));
                imageList.add(image);
            }
        }
        db.close();
     }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e+"");
     }
     return imageList;
 }
```

**Model class**

```
public class ImgModel {
private int _id;
private String imageUrl;
private String name;

//Getters and Setters
public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
 }
}
```

**Activity**

checking for internet

```
  NetworkUtils utils = new NetworkUtils(getApplicationContext());
    if(utils.isConnectingToInternet())
    {
        getSpinnerData();
    }
    else
    {
        List<ImgModel> imageList = db.getAllImage();
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(imageList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Adding image in db

```
 private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ImgModel model1 = new ImgModel();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String link = json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL);
            String imgname = json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);
            model1.setImageUrl(link);
            model1.setName(imgname);
            db.addImage(model1);    // add data in database
            Log.e("urls","===>"+link);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listimg.add(model1);
    }
```

Comment: you want to access the image after you are online right?

Comment: if m i online then image load from json but when i am not online then it access from database

Comment: You are not storing the image in database you are just saving the url. To get the image from database you have to save the image in database, for that you have to use BLOB as a datatype, try referring this [tutorial](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/12/23/store-image-android-sqlite-retrieve-it/) and if you face a problem, comment back with it.

Comment: Rishabh Lashkari thanks but first time i am fatching image from json then store in data base this tutorial is not for that..

Comment: I done know exactly how you can do this, but inserting images into a database is a very bad way and you must avoid that.also you can use Glide and Picasso

Answer (score 0):

Use some Image Library like Picasso,Glide or Fresco which will cache the image for you , you just have to store the url which you are doing now , it will download the image only 1 time , after that it will fetch the image from cache

Comment: i am also using volley  Imageloader.. in my activity

Comment: Okay , You can try changing the library if you want , i recommend Glide , as its the lightest of all , Picasso and glide are one in same thing , bt fresco is best in terms of image caching , but it has a bug of freezing UI sometimes so i dont recommend it 

Using BLOB to store image is not a good idea as it will only make your DB heavy

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso

After importing library you just have to use one line

 Picasso.with(this).load(uri).fit().placeholder(drawable).into(imageview);

What this will do is that it will check the cache whether your image is already there or not , if yes then it will load the image from cache otherwise it will download it from web